# Why was a Klingon targ aboard the Enterprise during "The Schizoid Man"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

At the end of the episode "The Schizoid Man", it is implied that Data wrestled a Klingon targ:

> RIKER: Does wrestling with a Klingon targ ring a bell?
>
> PICARD: Mr. Crusher, take us out of orbit.
>
> WESLEY: Aye, sir.
>
> DATA: Did I win?

Why would the *Enterprise* have a targ aboard?  Is it someone's pet?  (Worf had a pet targ *as a child*, but he does not appear with a real one as an adult.)  Is it food?  Is it being carried as cargo?

Comment: I read that as Riker trying to persuade Data of something he likely didn't actually do (remember, Data has no memory of this time period and actually thinks he may have behaved unbecomingly during his being invaded by Graves' personality).

Comment: I don't interpret this dialog to imply the Enterprise-D had a targ aboard. It may have been a rhetorical question by Riker.

Comment: Ehhh.  There's this thing called a holodeck.  Data could have wrestled with a targ there.  Or, Riker is just pulling Data's leg.

Comment: This was obviously a joke...

Comment: “Is it food?” Replicated targ just doesn’t taste the same.

Comment: Riker is obviously pulling Data's leg. And why not - in the same season, Riker has already pulled Data's arm....*rimshot*!

Comment: Targs must be mighty tough if Data questioned if he defeated one. The script should have called for Data fighting ten of them. And I though I agree that Riker was likely joking, this can't be known for certain based only on the episode.

Comment: Adult Worf *does* appear with a targ in S1:Where No One Has Gone Before

Comment: @NKCampbell: Yeah, the picture of targ on Memory Alpha comes from that episode.  However, it was a hallucination caused by where the *Enterprise* was in that episode.  Data would not have been able to wrestle this hallucination in "The Schizoid Man".

Comment: No I get it - it's just wildly accurate semantics joking :) Your question states that Worf *does not* appear with a targ when he is an adult - when in fact, he does ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell: Thank you, I have edited the question to address that.

Answer (score 4):

There are no targs on the Enterprise. Riker is merely telling a joke at Data's expense.

Comment: And while that may be true, can you offer any evidence to back this bold claim up? Note that the holodeck can undoubtedly conjure up a targ on command...

Comment: @Valorum Dr. Graves was too busy trying to get in his assistant's pants with Data's body to stop at the holodeck. The period in which Data remembers nothing was confined entirely to this time where Dr. Graves has hijacked his body.

Comment: Again, that seems like supposition. I'm not saying you're wrong, but i'm guessing you've found no evidence to back it up (and nor has anyone else, which is why it's gone unanswered for three weeks).

Comment: I agree with Valorum that you might be correct, but I am looking for an answer supported by a source.  Even a licensed book or game would be sufficient evidence.

Comment: @Valorum - I'd posit it's gone unanswered for weeks and has -4 votes because it's a bad question based on a poor understanding of a (or maybe a poorly written) joke. Anyone follow Frakes or Spiner on Twitter? Maybe they can address it? The original script doesn't appear to have this exchange in it http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/131.txt - though there is a bit of business at the end that was removed (and seemingly replaced by the lines in question) that clearly indicate joke time

Comment: @NKCampbell - Asking an actor (or the writer/s) would be an excellent way of getting a sourced answer.

Comment: @DrSheldon Why is the burden of proof on me, exactly? We never see evidence that there is a targ on the ship anywhere for any reason.  We never see Dr. Graves as Data go to the holodeck, and no character mentions him going to the holodeck in an episode where every erratic thing "Data" does is directly relevant to the plot, is mentioned explicitly, and watched very carefully by all other characters. It never comes up before Riker's joke. Wouldn't the burden of proof be on you, with your claim  implicit in your question that a targ would have a purpose on the Enterprise?

Comment: @Joe - under the generally accepted procedures of the site, the burden of proof is on you because you provided the answer. Now - I'm inclined to agree with your answer - it's common sense. But - but generally, in terms of what is looked for on this site - its better to include the references in the answer - with links if possible. Are they required? No - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer .  Are they good? Yes - https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/how-to-comment-on-answers-lacking-citations

Comment: @Joe - The burden of proof is on you because you're telling me two facts without backing them up in any way. How am I to judge that your answer is any better than one that says ***"There are targs on the Enterprise. Riker wasn't merely telling a joke at Data's expense."***

Comment: @NKCampbell Are there guidelines on how to answer loaded questions (aside from... not answering them)? I am genuinely asking here because the question has the assumption in it that, if Riker says there is a targ, there must actually be one. If this were a debate outside of stack exchange, this would be understood as logically fallacious to begin with, because questioner would have to provide evidence that Riker was serious when he made the statement.

Comment: @Valorum may have a better answer as to the guidelines - your question is a good one imo. I think the logical fallacy approach is an equally valid tack to take in response to OP's question - you could cite common idiomatic usage of the term 'ring a bell', comedy tropes, etc...in an attempt to prove that it should be painfully obvious that it's a joke - does that make sense?

Comment: @Valorum The burden of proof of any claim rests with the claimant. Your hypothetical answer is merely the embedded assumption in the question restated as an answer. Regardless of whether it's stated as a question or an answer, it was the initial claim in this discussion, so the burden doesn't rest upon me or anyone else who attempts to provide an answer, because DrSheldon is begging the question re: "Is every statement from Riker literally true?"

Comment: @NKCampbell That is a good suggestion. I think I will watch that bit of the episode again and revise. I seem to remember that there is a particular jingle they play for the end-of-episode joke in these early TNG seasons, and I don't remember if they did it there but I bet they probably did.

Comment: @Joe - I'm not saying you *can't* give an answer that's unsupported, just that such an answer is generally closer to a comment than an answer. Adding in some info about a stinger that they play when they make a joke would turn this from a bad answer into an excellent one